# WordPress is giving me 404 for all pages except the homepage

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I guess the problem lies within the .htaccess file or the server, but I can't seem to fix it. It only shows homepage and no other pages... Other pages only with a 404 page. Did use the solutions of the same problem in other questions, but that doesn't help...

.HTACCESS$

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Hope someone can help me? I'm also working with custom fields. But the site has always worked, until now... (https://open-ieper.be)

Comment: Locally it's working with '
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /OpenIeper/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /OpenIeper/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress'

Comment: Did you check in your server config that htaccess files were allowed and `mod_rewrite` was enabled ? Also, I see you're using a rewrite base locally, what about your remote server ? Is it in root folder or do you need also a rewrite base ?